# hdfs c program fails with " exception: ExceptionUtils::getStackTrace error.)"

Tags: c++, file, hadoop, hdfs

I've installed and configured hadoop 2.8.4 on my ubuntu 18.04, hdfs command runs ok and my java program that runs hdfs runs ok, yarn runs ok.

```
hdfs@ubuntu:$ hdfs dfs -ls /tmp
Found 8 items
drwx-w----   - hdfs supergroup          0 2018-07-30 04:25 /tmp/NOTES.txt
drwx------   - hdfs supergroup          0 2018-07-29 13:12 /tmp/hadoop-yarn
drwx-wx-wx   - hdfs supergroup          0 2018-08-19 03:16 /tmp/hive
drwx-w----   - hdfs supergroup          0 2018-07-30 04:30 /tmp/myNotes.txt
drwx-w----   - hdfs supergroup          0 2018-07-30 04:34 /tmp/myNotes2.txt
drwx-w----   - hdfs supergroup          0 2018-07-30 04:37 /tmp/myNotes3.txt
drwx-w----   - hdfs supergroup          0 2018-07-30 04:38 /tmp/myNotes4.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 hdfs supergroup         15 2018-07-30 04:24 /tmp/testfile.txt
```

Then I tried a c program as from the book "Hadoop 2 quick-start guide", mytest.c file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"hdfs.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    hdfsFS fs=hdfsConnect("default",0);
    hdfsFile writeFile=hdfsOpenFile(fs,argv[1],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0,0,0);
    if(!writeFile){
        fprintf(stderr,"open %s for write failed\n",argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    char buffer[]="hw";
    tSize numWrittenBytes=hdfsWrite(fs,writeFile,(void*)buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
    if(hdfsFlush(fs,writeFile)){
        fprintf(stderr,"flush failed for %s\n",argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    hdfsCloseFile(fs, writeFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I have a shell script to build and run it with user hdfs:

```
. $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

gcc mytest.c -I$HADOOP_LIB/include -I$HADOOP_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include -L$HADOOP_LIB/native -L$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -lhdfs -o mytest
export CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_LIB/native:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./mytest "file01"
```

Seems the function "hdfsOpenFile" failed:

```
loadFileSystems error:
(unable to get stack trace for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception: ExceptionUtils::getStackTrace error.)
hdfsBuilderConnect(forceNewInstance=0, nn=default, port=0, kerbTicketCachePath=(NULL), userName=(NULL)) error:
(unable to get stack trace for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception: ExceptionUtils::getStackTrace error.)
hdfsOpenFile(file01.txt): constructNewObjectOfPath error:
(unable to get stack trace for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception: ExceptionUtils::getStackTrace error.)
open file01 for write failed
```

Would you help to tell why my "hdfsOpenFile" failed and how to fix my issue? Thanks

Comment: `open file01 for write failed` -- That error must be important, no?  Is `file01` a valid file path / name?

Comment: I wish my program will create a hdfs file named "file01". Anything wrong with my program?

Comment: Maybe your program, and maybe any program, cannot create a file named "file01" and has nothing to do with hadoop.  `#include <fstream> int main() { std::ofstream("file01"); }` -- Maybe something simple as that also fails.

Comment: Have you found any answer to this?